# How to manage Glass power in blender

Tags: modeling, materials

I want to have a little gap between the lipstick color and the glass edge you can see the image below

[image]

According to image, you can see the blue arrow and red arrow gap is to large. I want a little closer gap like the real lipstick.

[image]

Actually, I already made closer in 3d but the result is too large gap in render. How can I make like in the real image?

[image]

this is my node tree for the glass material.

Comment: Hello, try to tweak the IOR value of the Glass node

Comment: thank you very much I got it ...

Comment: @ThuRa Hello and welcome. This site is not a regular forum. Please don't reply "Thanks" as an answer or comment, instead [upvote the post that helped you](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote). If you feel it completely solved your issue consider [marking it as accepted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Tweak the *IOR* (index of refraction) of the *Glass* node, it's the value that will determine how much the rays are deflected by the glass:

[image]